Android PdfRenderer from RAM data in insolatedProcess service
I'm trying to run the PdfRenderer in a Service with isoletedProcess=true.
The problem is with ParcelFileDescriptor. I have tried:

to create a tmp file File.createTmpFile (No access to file system)
to download using HTTP (No access to internet)
to create a pipe ParcelFileDescriptor.createPipe() (Descriptor is not seekable)

Now I have data stored to a byte[], so how I can obtain the ParcelFileDescriptor using it?
